# Redirection in the homepage?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, http-headers, search-engine

I'm working on a website that deals with many languages and when a user enters to `example.com`, a little PHP script detects the user browser's preferred language (based on the `Accept-Language header`) and based on that it redirects using `header(Location: ...)` to `en.example.com`, `it.example.com`, `es.example.com`, etc.
Now, this works perfectly but I found that search engines fail at indexing the homepage properly. I don't know much about the HTTP protocol but I realize I'm doing something wrong here. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you do this?
In your case - i will never see your Website in german when i call the site form a agent that execepts it or es only ...

You should give 'users' the posibillity to choose whiche language they want to have ... and then google and co should be nearer your friend

Comment: Well, even Google does this somehow. When you enter `google.com`, it detects your location and based on that it redirects you to `google.co.jp` or `google.co.in`, `google.fr`. Also, I give users the possibility of changing their preferred language (and saving it into a cookie).

Comment: In this case (look if cookie exists, if not find (possible might language) and safe it in cookie and redirect, if cookie exists do nothing it will work. Buttons to switch the language are links on every page of your site ....

Comment: Good idea. That way even people that don't accept cookies will be able to change their language.. I hope that search engines can crawl header redirections. Thanks for your answer!